# Python function to convert type if not given type else do nothing

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple variables getting converted to `numpy.array`. so the input variable may be already `numpy.array` or a `list`. But I want to avoid creating multiple `isinstance` checks to convert .

Any builtin function which type casts if not already the type else does nothing. (Like a `ternary operator` or a null checking `(var or defaultval)` )

Or in other words simply converting to same type has any effect in python?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that does this, but you can easily write a function that does it.

Comment: `def c(val): return val if isinstance(val, numpy.array) else numpy.array(val)`…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`numpy.asarray()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray) is for: if it is passed an array it will return it. You can safely call this on your "maybe arrays", and it will be a no-op:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
... arr = np.arange(3)
... np.asarray(arr) is arr
True
```

On the other hand if you pass in a list or other sequence, it will be converted to a numpy array. And if you also want to allow numpy ndarray subclasses to be preserved, use `np.asanyarray()`.